# RecyclerView перемешивает элементы

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Я сделал RecyclerView, и если в нём много элементов, то он перемешивает элементы. В чём может быть проблема ?

```
inner class AboutUsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<AboutUsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        inner class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
            var imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_show)
            var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
            var subtitle = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sub_text)
            val ad = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_text)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.about_us_element, parent, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return texts.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.name.text = texts[position]
            holder.subtitle.text = subtitles[position]
            if(position == 0){
                holder.ad.text = ""
            }
            if (position == 0 || position == 1){
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(applicationContext.resources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).toBitmap())
            } else {
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(getPicFromAsset(files[position - 2]))
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val sound: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.simple_tap)
                sound.isLooping = false
                sound.setOnCompletionListener {
                    when (position) {
                        0 -> {
                            if (showAd) {
                                mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
                                    val adIntent = Intent(applicationContext, ChooseImage::class.java)
                                    override fun onAdOpened() {
                                    }

                                    override fun onAdClosed() {
                                        adIntent.putExtra("bundle",extras)
                                        startActivity(adIntent)
                                        val ad = AdRequest.Builder()
                                                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
                                                .build()
                                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(ad)
                                    }
                                }
                                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                                    mInterstitialAd.show()
                                } else {
                                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ChooseImage::class.java)
                                    intent.putExtra("bundle",extras)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }
                            } else {
                                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ChooseImage::class.java)
                                intent.putExtra("bundle",extras)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(array[position - 1]))
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                }
                sound.start()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Используйте getAdapterPosition() вместо position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно увидеть в коде, который я прикреплял, я присваивал каждому холдеру позицию, по которой и определял картинку. Убрав это, и используя позицию,которая передаётся как аргумент, у меня всё заработал.

Answer (score 0):

Сам RecyclerView ничего перемешивать не может. Все что делает RecyclerView это отображает список который вы ему задали для отображения.

В вашем коде непонятно как вообще список данных попадает в ваш RecyclerView. Но вам стоит искать проблему именно там где вы этот список получаете/генерируете.